# Access MySQL database from virtual machine hard drive (EBS volume) in Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2

I had an Ubuntu image that was corrupted and will not longer boot (hosted with EC2).  This is just a problem with the OS booting and not a problem wit the actual EBS volume.  So I have mounted the EBS volume on another EC2 instance which is working.  How can I access the MySQL database on the EBS volume I have mounted so I can copy the data over to the MySQL instance running on the working box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the data directory in my.cnf to the directory on EBS and restart mysql. Once you see the data do a mysqldump switch the data directory back restart mysql.. then do the import